# pandas groupby.apply is slow, even on small DataSets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to aggregate a pandas DataFrame by two group variables and do calculations on each group. As I want to mix columns, I use [dataframe.groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)
The following code works but is inexplicably slow. 3 seconds to aggregate 4000 rows.
When I change the code to one group variable, it is just half the time, maybe a little less.
Any ideas, why it is so slow?

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4000,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df['group'] = random.choices([0, 0, 1, 1],k=4000)
df["grupp"]=  random.choices([2, 3, 4, 2],k=4000)
df

def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['c_d_prodsum'] = (x['c'] * x['d']).sum()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['c_d_prodsum'])

import time
start = time.time()
%timeit b=df.groupby(['group','grupp']).apply(f)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

On my machine, it shows  `33.2 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop` and `2.77` as the number of seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get better performance if you restrict yourself to only those functions provided by pandas.

For instance...

```py
def totime():
    df['c*d'] = df['c']*df['d']
    d = df.groupby(['group','grupp'])['c*d'].sum().rename('c_d_prodsum')

%timeit totime()
```

shows `842 µs ± 3.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)`

Comment: Thank you. So I assume, that groupby.apply is only suitable for a small amount of groups? Or is there a better way to use apply?

Comment: I would say groupby.apply is suitable until it is not. In general, I never look to speed up code until it is obvious that the original, perhaps naive version, is too inefficient for its intended use.